# How to add multiple QPushButtons to a QTableView?

Tags: python, pyside

I have a `QTableView` to which I want to set a `QPushButton` for every row. I am doing this as follows within my class derived from `QWidget` following an example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411101/pyside-qtableview-example):

```
 for index in range(number_rows):
        btn_sell = QPushButton("Edit", self)
        btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.button_edit)
        table_view.setIndexWidget(table_view.model().index(index, 4), btn_sell)
```

If the table is drawn and I click on one of the `QPushButton` the method `self.button_edit` is called - but which one? It does not seem that an 'event' of any sort is given to `self.button_edit`, so how can I find the row-index of the `QPushButton` that was clicked within the `button_edit` method?

Maybe there is a different way altogether to add a button to each row of a table?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your event handler will look similar to this:

```
def handleButtonClicked(self):
    button = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
    # or button = self.sender()
    index = self.table.indexAt(button.pos())
    if index.isValid():
        print(index.row(), index.column())
```

This uses the [`indexAt`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#indexAt) function to get the button's position.

For clarity, my script looks like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        data1 = ['row1','row2','row3','row4']
        data2 = ['1','2.0','3.00000001','3.9999999']

        self.table.setRowCount(4)

        for index in range(4):
            item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data1[index])
            self.table.setItem(index,0,item1)
            item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data2[index])
            self.table.setItem(index,1,item2)
            self.btn_sell = QtGui.QPushButton('Edit')
            self.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
            self.table.setCellWidget(index,2,self.btn_sell)

    def handleButtonClicked(self):
        button = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
        # or button = self.sender()
        index = self.table.indexAt(button.pos())
        if index.isValid():
            print(index.row(), index.column())
```

Which will produce a small GUI like this:

[image: small gui]

When the `Edit` buttons are clicked, it prints, to the console:

```
(0, 2)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
```

The first element is your row index, the second is your column (remember it is 0 based, which is why it shows 2, not 3 - despite the column headers).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Would the commented part `self.sender()` work too?

Comment: Important to note, that you use `QTableWidget` here instead of `QTableView` as the OP

Comment: For PyQT5, I had to replace `QtGui` by `QtWidgets` but it works like a charm. Thank you @Andy

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom button.

```
class IndexedButtonWidget(QPushButton):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(QPushButton, self).__init__(parent=parent)
    self.button_row = 0
    self.button_column = 0
```

After that create a button object.

```
self.btn_sell = IndexedButtonWidget('Edit')
self.btn_sell.button_row = row
self.btn_sell.button_column = column
self.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)

def handleButtonClicked(self):
    button = self.sender()
    print(button.button_row)
    print(button.button_column)
```

Example:

```
class IndexedButtonWidget(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(QPushButton, self).__init__(parent=parent)
    self.button_row = 0
    self.button_column = 0

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        data1 = ['row1','row2','row3','row4']
        data2 = ['1','2.0','3.00000001','3.9999999']

        self.table.setRowCount(4)

        for index in range(4):
            item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data1[index])
            self.table.setItem(index,0,item1)
            item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data2[index])
            self.table.setItem(index,1,item2)
            self.btn_sell = IndexedButtonWidget('Edit')
            self.btn_sell.button_row = index
            self.btn_sell.button_column = 2
            self.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
            self.table.setCellWidget(index,2,self.btn_sell)

    def handleButtonClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        print(button.button_row)
        print(button.button_column)
```