# How to access a given dataelement in a pyside Model?

Tags: python, pyside

I am new to `pyside` and have the following situation: I have a model/view in which a column is replaced by push buttons (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148968/how-to-add-multiple-qpushbuttons-to-a-qtableview)). When pressing the button I am able to get the index of this particular button. But how to access e.g. the first element in the same row?

My idea was to create an index pointing to the first element in the row. But how to create a `QModelIndex`? The [documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QModelIndex.html#PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex) does not say to.

Maybe there is another way to 'get/extract' the data from the model in the first column of the row? The second column? The whole row?

I am not sure if the following works:

```
index2 = index.child(index.row(), 0)
```

Also, I get the following error (with python3.3):

```
model.data(index)
TypeError: data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'role'
```

although the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148968/how-to-add-multiple-qpushbuttons-to-a-qtableview) states that `role` is optional. And what the heck is a role? I want the content of a given data cell.

So how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, but mostly by 'guessing'. The `pyside` documentation is really bad in this aspect...

The solution is:

```
index2 = index.child(index.row(), 1)
element = model.data(index2, Qt.DisplayRole)
```

if `index` is the index the `PushButton` is located, and you want to get the element of the same row, but the second column.

- What `index.child()` really does: No idea
- Why I need a role for `model.data`: No idea

But it seems to work...