# Widgets as data in QTableView

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, model-view

I'm trying to make a table-based interface as follows:

```
| QComboBox | QPushButton | Empty       |
| Some data | Some data   | QPushButton |
| Some data | Some data   | Empty       | (all additional rows resemble this one)
```

In the first row, I want a `QComboBox` with some selections that are defined based on the return value of another function, and the `QPushButton`s are attached to triggers which will insert or remove data.

Assuming I can generate the `QComboBox` and `QPushButton`s on my own, how can I get them to be inserted into the `QTableView` in those locations? I currently have a model which properly stores the data that need to be shown in the locations marked "Some data" and to return no data for the special or "Empty" locations, and I have a `QStyledItemDelegate` which is supposed to insert these widgets for me, but it only inserts them when I double click the field (which I suppose is the trigger for `createEditor`).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457935/pyqt4-adding-combobox-in-qtableview/30460687#30460687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

`QAbstractItemView` (and by extension `QTableView`) have a method called `setIndexWidget` which can be used to place a widget in a location. By using that method, I can insert the appropriate widgets on initialization without relying on a delegate at all.