# PyQT4. Adding combobox in Qtableview in different columns and same row

Tags: combobox, pyqt4, qtableview

I am trying to add combo boxes to the first row of my QTableView() to different columns. I have searched for other solutions, [PyQT4: Adding combobox in Qtableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457935/pyqt4-adding-combobox-in-qtableview)
 but they seem to add multiple comboboxes in the same COLUMN, I need to do that in different column for the same row.

Need assistance please.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider posting your codes and more details on the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Hi, my code is similar to the one in the link I posted. That code produces combo boxes in a  single column. I am looking to have the the combo boxes in a single row but different columns

Comment: @GodwinMafireyi. Can you really not see that swapping the row/column indexes will do what you want? This is pretty basic stuff - maybe you need to read tutorial on using for-loops in python.