# QTableWidget - Edit the content into table with edit button and lock the previous rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

1. I have tried the integrate button `edit` into the `column "A1"` ([similar like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148968/how-to-add-multiple-qpushbuttons-to-a-qtableview)) but unfortunately without success so far.
2. I would like to add `edit button` into every row in `column "A1"` and don't be able to edit the rows as long as the edit button is not pressed.
3. Next Thing what I tried and didn't find the solution that the `cell "A2"` showed into table layers (`cell "B1"`), but its content is *disabled* to edit.

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3 as sql
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, os

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Tabs & QWidget
        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.general = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layers = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.general, "General")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.layers, "Layers")

        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)

        # QTableWidget
        self.general_table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.general)
        self.layers_table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.layers)


        # Geometry
        self.tabs.setGeometry(0, 0, 1500, 500)
        self.general_table.setGeometry(0,0,1490,500)
        self.layers_table.setGeometry(0,0,1490,500)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1520,720)
        self.setFixedSize(1520, 720)
        self.setHeader()

        # Set Column Width and resize the conctext automatically

        header = self.general_table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)

        header = self.layers_table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)


        # PushButton
        add_record = QtGui.QPushButton("Add Record")
        delete_record = QtGui.QPushButton("Delete Record")

        # Layout
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(cWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        layout.addWidget(add_record)
        layout.addWidget(delete_record)

        # Connect SIGNAL
        self.connect(add_record, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addRecord)
        self.connect(delete_record, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.deleteRecord)



    def whatTab(self):
        current_index = self.tabs.currentIndex()
        self.tabs.currentWidget()
        return current_index

    def addRecord(self):
        rcount_general = self.general_table.rowCount()
        self.general_table.insertRow(rcount_general)
        self.layers_table.insertRow(rcount_general)
        self.fullNone(rcount_general)


    def deleteRecord(self):
        self.general_table.removeRow(self.general_table.currentIndex().row())
        self.layers_table.removeRow(self.general_table.currentIndex().row())


    def setHeader(self):
        # General
        self.general_table.setRowCount(1)
        self.general_table.setColumnCount(6)
        self.general_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", 
                                                "A5", "A6)"])

        # Layers                                        
        self.layers_table.setRowCount(1)
        self.layers_table.setColumnCount(8)                                       
        self.layers_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", 
                                                "B5", "B6", "B8", "B9"])

        self.fullNone(0)

    def fullNone(self, row):

        for col in range(0, 6, 1):
            self.general_table.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("None"))

        for col in range(0, 8, 1):
            self.layers_table.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("None"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What you want is to enable editing with a button that is in each row?